# Why Html.fromHtml() is not not working for <strike> or <s> or <del> tag

Tags: android, html, strikethrough

Basically I'm trying to show the `strikeThrough` text on the `textView` from html text . I've tried all other tags like `bold` , `italic` etc they're shown perfectly without any problem but when I'm trying to show the `<strike> or <s> or <del>` tag text it's showing the text without the **strikes** . Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Code:

```
 String s="<p dir=\"ltr\"><del>a</del><del>b</del><del>c</del></p> ";
 txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply put, it's  not supported. Html.fromHtml() handles a different set of of tags than static text supports. Here's a list of the tags (I don't know if it's complete):

```
<a> (supports attribute "href")
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div>
<em>
<font> (supports attributes "color" and "face")
<i>
<img> (supports attribute "src". Note: you have to include an ImageGetter to handle retrieving a Drawable for this tag)
<p>
<small>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

You can check the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java).

You have to use a library which have extended capabilities to get it working, or write one yourself. Check this [one](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview) or this [one](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android). There are tons of others on Github, or if you want to write it, i'm sure you can find the code by just Googling.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your enlightenment , although I'm not using your suggested libs . Now I'm using [this library] [ https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat ]

Comment: All's fine as long as it gets the  job done. Be careful though, as this is a deprecated library. So no more updates, ever.